# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings return The given key was not present in the dictionary error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am getting an error on ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
the error is The give key was not present in the dictionary

Code:

```
string userPass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dev_pass"];
```

Comment: You need `.ToString()` at the end. Ie `string userPass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dev_pass"].ToString();` if that's not it please show us you app/web config

Comment: @JeremyThompson the AppSettings dictionary values are strings, so calling `ToString` is redundant and the error will persist. That error is more related to the key not being added to the dictionary...it hasn't been defined

Comment: @Leo I looked up the msdn documentation and it says you're right. For years though I've been (or found myself) explicitly adding ToString. Hmmm. Anyway OP needs to show config app settings.

Comment: There may be multiple web.config files in your project. Ensure the key is found in the file at the root.

Comment: I'm using MVC C# and there is 2 web.config file, the first is in the root directory of the system and second is in Views folder

Answer (score 1):

If you're using classic ASP.NET, then make sure you added that key to the `web.config`'s app settings...

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="dev_pass" value="THE_VALUE" />
  </appSettings>
```

If you're using ASP.NET Core, the make sure you follow ASP.NET Core's guidelines to retrieve settings from `appsettings.json`. Assuming your `appsettings.json` is configured the following way...

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "dev_pass": "THE VALUE"
    }
}
```

Then create this class...

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string dev_pass{ get; set; }
}
```

and then configure it as a service...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

Comment: But the dev_pass is existing in my web.config file and I already use the system with that code, it just happen now, what do you think the problem?

Comment: Do you have different AppSettings for different build configurations (Debug, Release, etc.)? Have you got config sources configured? Can you post your web.config ?